# Can I make this function more concise

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript snippet and am wondering if I can calculate `amount` and `users` in a single pass of the `reduce` function?

```
root.children.forEach(function(v) {

    v.amount = v.children.reduce(function(a, b) {
        console.log(a);
        return {
            amount: a.amount + b.amount
        }
    }, {
        'amount': 0
    }).amount

    v.users = v.children.reduce(function(a, b) {
        console.log(a);
        return {
            users: a.users + b.users
        }
    }, {
        'users': 0
    }).users

})
```

Comment: Could you explain what the code does or achieves? What are `children`, etc?

Comment: so each root.children has children again? Because v contains the children object and you are then writing v.children ...

Comment: @AndrewLi it is part of a bigger function that builds a hierarchical json file from a csv input

Comment: `v.amount = v.children.reduce((a, b) => a + b.amount, 0);` Same story for users...

Comment: @Azamantes: Then you're still looping twice.

Comment: If the purpose is to update all the nodes of your tree like this, it is going to be very inefficient, including the much upvoted answers that were given.

Comment: @Cerbrus then combine it.

Comment: @Azamantes - I'm with cerbrus: combining it is the point of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could a single [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop.

```js
var root = {
        children: [
            { children: [
                { amount: 2, users: 3 },
                { amount: 7, users: 5 }
            ]}
        ]
    };

root.children.forEach(function(v) {
    v.amount = 0;
    v.users = 0;

    v.children.forEach(function(a) {
        v.amount += a.amount;
        v.users += a.users;
    });
});
console.log(root);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this code is not currently working - the parents are showing as 0

Comment: dv, care to comment?

Comment: did you amend the code slightly? it now functions ok for me - thanks. I will probably use your solution as it is simpler for a js nooby like me to get my head around!

Comment: ahh - that will explain the zeros when integrated into main code. Apologies for initial dv (although I just dv'd from 1 =>0 and would never have dv'd from 0 => -1). I have amended to the accepted answer as it is a little simpler for me to get my head around.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do that like below,

```
root.children.forEach(function(v) {
    var obj = v.children.reduce(function(a, b) {
        a.amount += b.amount;
        a.users += a.users;
    }, {'amount': 0, 'users' : 0 });
    v.amount = obj.amount;
    v.users = obj.users;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you can literally combine the two methods into one:

```
root.children.forEach(function(v) {        
    var result = v.children.reduce(
        function(a, b) {
            return {
                amount: a.amount + b.amount,
                users: a.users + b.users
            };
        },
        { amount: 0, users: 0 }
    ); // ^ Note that I left out the quotes there. In this case, they're optional.

    v.amount = result.amount;
    v.users= result.users;
});
```

Comment: combining is what I thought would be possible - just not know the basics of js meant implementing was tricky!